# Install postgresql 9.2 on debian wheezy (on virtualbox)

Tags: postgresql, virtualbox

I have virtualbox with Debian Wheezy. I'm trying to install Postgresql 9.2 on it. When I trying do it by [this](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/) instruction i have next:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.2 : Depends: postgresql-common (>= 135~) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ssl-cert but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install postgresql-common:

```
apt-get install postgresql-common
```

I got next:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-common : Depends: ssl-cert (>= 1.0.11) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

When I try to install ssl-cert:

```
apt-get install ssl-cert
```

I got next:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ssl-cert is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ssl-cert' has no installation candidate
```

I'm novice in Linux, please help me install Postgresql 9.2

There is my `sources.list`

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0.0 _Wheezy_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 201305$

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0.0 _Wheezy_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20130504$

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
# deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

Comment: I was run apt-get update before install, it didn't help

Comment: I added `sources.list` in my question, because in comments 15 characters max message length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
```

Make sure you use the appropriate mirror for your location.

Run `aptitude update` or `apt-get update` and finish the installation.

The interactive mode of `aptitude` is quite useful to solve dependencies.